# generating non repeating random number in java

Tags: java

i am making a game which will ask different questions in java. questions are stored in some arraylist. 
My problem is that these questions should not be repeated. and if all questions has been asked then program should stop. i have used java random function. but it is failed . any help will be appreciable 
Regards

Comment: How has Random failed? Do you seed it, e.g. with the current time?

Comment: [`shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List%29) the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy list of questions to a temporary list, and

```
while(list.size() > 0){
     int i = Math.floor(Math.Random() * list.size());
     list.get(i); //do something with question
     list.remove(i);
}
```

This loops as long as list has elements, pulling a random element out and then removes it from list.

---

edit for clarification - this ensures you don't get duplicates

Comment: all i want to do is select any random question from an arraylist, and make sure that the question doesn't gets repeated after it's been asked.. the way you are telling is will go orderwise as far as i guess so. now i hope my problem is clear to you.. if there are 50 questions. i want any of the question from all the 50's to be asked. no matter it might be the 40th one first time. but after it has been asked , it shouldn't be repeated. All 50 questions should be asked randomly

Comment: That's exactly what this code does, you generate a random number between 0 and the size of the list, then pull out the question, and remove the question from the list at that index to make sure it isn't pulled again. Then after that is removed, generate another random number using the new size (size - n) of the list.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to display the questions in a random order. There is a simple solution to this problem. Use the method `java.util.Collections.shuffle` to randomly permute the questions in the list. And then iterate from the beginning through the list. This algorithm has linear time and space complexity.

Comment: But i dont want to repeat any question when program is executing. if all questions appeared it should give me a message like "all questions done".

Comment: You only shuffle once. When you reach the end of the list -> "all done"

Comment: `shuffle` ia like shuffling a deck of cards.  You won't get repeats.

Comment: so after getting one question from list i need to remove it from list. and shuffle that list again ?

Comment: i am using this code right now
public Question getQuestionWhichIsNotAppearedOfType(boolean type) {

Question toReturn = new Question(0, "Question is Empty", true);
 while (appearedQuestions.size() > 0) {
 int i = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * appearedQuestions.size());
   toReturn = appearedQuestions.get(i); // do something with question

   appearedQuestions.remove(i);
  }
  
  return toReturn;

 }

Comment: @MuhammadMaaz You don't need to shuffle the list again. Shuffle once, get a question, then get the next question, then get the next one, and so on until you reach the end.

Comment: all i want to do is select any random question from an arraylist, and make sure that the question doesn't gets repeated after it's been asked.. the way you are telling is will go orderwise as far as i guess so. now i hope my problem is clear to you.. if there are 50 questions. i want any of the question from all the 50's to be asked. no matter it might be the 40th one first time. but after it has been asked , it shouldn't be repeated. All 50 questions should be asked randomly

Comment: (1) shuffle the list (2) use an iterator to go through the list (3) when the iterator `hasNext` returns false, you have exhausted your list of questions.